# Reserve 2 lines of text for incoming sentences

Tags: html, css

I need your help to reserve 2 lines of text. I implemented a typing effect for sentences and at some point the sentences are too long and continue on the next line. I want to reserve 2 lines no matter how much text is currently shown to avoid the shift of the following content.

Looking forward to your help!

Video attached: https://dl3.pushbulletusercontent.com/K6GJgUrUpL3707N28WR6xS6fh7OIBj0S/1604316989096.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at some CSS properties that will let you achieve what you want
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/min-height
Give that HTML container a class

`<div class="typingEffectBox">...</div>`

and then use the properties you want to make that container with a minimum desired height

`.typingEffectBox { min-height: 20px;}`

Did you try any CSS styling to get the job done? Show us what you tried so we can help you better